# does Alarm Manager persist even after reboot?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am really new to android, I have been researching about alarms. I want to alarm if there is a birthday on that day. I've have used alarm manager. I was confused because i have read that it clears after reboot. I don't have an android phone so I'm just using the emulator.

Here's my code :

```
public void schedAlarm() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, contact.id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timetoAlarm, nextalarm, pendingIntent);
}
```

I made this BroadcastRecever in replace for AlarmSerivce
Here :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = "It Birthday!";
    CharSequence message =" Greet your friend.";
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Birthday", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    nm.notify(1, notif);
 }
```

is this enough??

Comment: By default, all alarms are canceled when a device shuts down.https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#boot

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A simple answer would be **NO**. But yes you can achieve this by creating a `BroadCastReceiver` which will start the Alarm while booting completes of the device.

Use `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />` for trapping boot activity in BroadCastReceiver class.

You need to add above line in AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoStartUp" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Can i just change AlarmService into a BroadCastRecever?

Comment: I dont know your AlarmService file's code, so i can't say `yes`, but i suggest you to create new one, so that if anything goes wrong, you have atleast your previous work ready :)

Comment: Yes, and you need to make changes in AndroidManifest.xml , as i said in my answer.

Comment: @Lucifer - Does Android clear all Alarms that we have set, after rebooting? If yes, we should set them after rebooting again!?

Comment: @Behzad, yes if the Alarms are set by code than it will surely get clear on reboot.

Comment: Please note that you also need to request the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your manifest.

Comment: Do I need to 're-register' all my alarms again in this receiver after I get a boot event?

Comment: I tried with same thing but not work for me toast is not display after reboot phone.

Answer (score 13):

Yes , you can make AlarmManager to work even after rebooting.
Perhaps this is the easiest way : add the below code in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

don't forget to include user-permission to the AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: it fires automatically just after reboot even if alarm is set an hour later.

Comment: Yes, Typically this would be called after a `PendingIntent` which would call `.AlarmReceiver` after a set period of time. By adding `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `QUICKBOOT_POWERON`. In the above answer `.AlarmReceiver` is called on boot (incorrect action), and the `PendingIntent` is still lost after boot.

Instead an additional receiver should be called from `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` that re initializes the `PendingIntent`

Answer (score 3):

in some phones only adding

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.Boot_COMPLETED" />
```

does not work you also have to add

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

along with previous one

Comment: Documentation of the latter one? Nothing found on developer.android.com...