# AlarmManager - expected behaviour of alarm when device time is changed?

Tags: android, android-alarms

Assume I set an alarm using the `AlarmManager.set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation)` method for 2pm today and the current time is 1pm. Now, if I change the time on the device to be 3pm (i.e. 3pm today or any day in the future), what should happen to my alarm? Should it trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that will not triggered by `AlarmManager`. So you should listen about time change actions and re-create the alarm.

Those actions are

```
Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK
Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
```

[does Alarm Manager persist even after reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034357/does-alarm-manager-persist-even-after-reboot) is a better answer to understand your problem and resolve that.

Comment: I think it depends on the alarm type u use. RTC could trigger if the time is changed manually by the user, but ElapsedRealTime should not.

Comment: The ACTION_TIME_TICK is not intented for such a use-case - it's received every second!

Answer (score 1):

Please ignore question. I've found my answer here and a suggested solution:

[Date and time change listener in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android)

If anyone has an alternative answer or solution, please do post!