# Notification Alert is not showing when time is change according to alert register time in mobile

Tags: cordova, notifications, localnotification

i register a notification like below:

```
var date= new Date();
date.setHour(15);
date.setMinutes(10);

window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    id:         "p10",  // A unique id of the notification
    date:       date,    // This expects a date object
    message:    "Notification appear",  // The message that is displayed
    title:      "hi",  // The title of the message
    json:       String,  // Data to be passed through the notification
    autoCancel: true, // Setting this flag and the notification is automatically cancelled when the user clicks it

}, callback, scope);
```

this work fine but if i change my mobile timing then this notification is not show?

if i change my mobile time according to alert time then i am not receiving alert.
why.?

Comment: Suppose you have set a alarm in 5.10pm. Are you changing your mobile time at 5.08pm or 5.10pm?

Comment: no 4:30 pm i change to 5:10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't specified any specific platform or plugin on your question, I took the freedom to check it on Android with [Cordova Local-Notification Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications). After extensive source reading I finally found ([here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/blob/master/src/android/LocalNotification.java) on method *add*) that the implementation uses [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to handle the waking of application to make the notification when it is on background.

After looking into AlarmManager, I quickly discovered that it doesn't really work if the time is manually altered. Instead, you should be tracking time chances on your app by yourself and then re-create the alarms for AlarmManager if such modification is noticed. The events to track on Android are

```
Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK
Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
```

as told by [Pankaj Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18463581/1744702).

Also, user [user:Lucifer] has on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034357/does-alarm-manager-persist-even-after-reboot) bounty-winning answer on question: *does Alarm Manager persist even after reboot?*. According to him the simple answer is **no**. For more detailed description, refer to his post there.

Comment: so we have to do some extra work if user altered the time. Thanks