# Alarm is not triggering on the same Date

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to reboot device on particular time so i am using alarm manager for that.below is the code of my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int timeHour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    private static int timeMinute = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 02);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
//        if(Calendar.getInstance().after(calendar)){
//            // Move to tomorrow
//            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
//        }
      alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

//
//        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
//                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
//                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

and this is my receiver

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static void rebootDevice() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("reboot \n");
        } catch (Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Gajanand", "onReceive: Triggered");

        rebootDevice();

    }
}
```

Yes code is working fine but not on the exact date.for example if i run the same code now. alarm not triggers if i change the date it triggers. i am not getting what is the problem with code and there is 10 seconds delay in triggering alarm. any help

Comment: did you check it ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197416/alarmmanager-not-working-after-phone-reboot

Comment: @AD10 that is not my problem i have another issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AlarmManager not working on some devices when the app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739669/android-alarmmanager-not-working-on-some-devices-when-the-app-is-closed)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

- ```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 02);
  ```

  Here you're setting `HOUR_OF_DAY` and `MINUTE` but the `SECOND` field still has its initial value, so the alarm won't be triggered exactly on the minute 
  (unless you called `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())` exactly on the minute, which is quite unlikely).

  Should be something like this:

  ```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
  calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // setting seconds to 0
  ```
- `setRepeating()` is inexact and doesn't work with Doze.

  For exact trigger times you should use exact alarms, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739886/3363481) answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the documentation

> **Note:** as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact.  If your
>        application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>        exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications
>       whose {@code targetSdkVersion} is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all
>        of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

Repeating alarms are always inexact so that they wont consume much battery. They may be fired a bit later than the expected time. If you want your alarm to exact, don't make it repeating. Set it again once you receive the alarm

Comment: i want alarm on the same date .

Comment: you cannot have it both ways. You can choose either one of these two. Either set it as one time and not repeating, it will be exact. But if you want it to repeat you wont be able to make it exact

Comment: then how can i repeat it for daily

Comment: To repeat exact alarms, you will have to set it again once you receive it