# Android: Will AlarmManager gets killed after shutdown

Tags: android, alarmmanager, shutdown, schedule

I am wondering will the alarm that I have set get destroyed after i shutting down the device or will it save the state of the schedule and broadcast straightaway when the user turning back on the device as long as the scheduled time is before the current time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [does Alarm Manager persist even after reboot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034357/does-alarm-manager-persist-even-after-reboot)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12034402/3981656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android: Will `AlarmManager` gets killed after shutdown  ?

**Ans: YES**

will it save the state of the schedule and broadcast straightaway when the user turning back on the device as long as the scheduled time is before the current time ?

**Ans: NO**

Resolution: Re-Register `AlarmManager` on `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast

Answer (score 3):

When device get rebooted alarm manager get destroyed.you need to re register the alarm manager after boot complete

add this permission in your manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and broadcast

```
<receiver
    android:name="your package name.MyBroadcast "
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

create a broadcast receiver

```
public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyBroadcast ";

public MyBroadcast () {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:

               // Register your alarm manager here

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It willl be destroyed after shutdown. Your should implement a RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver. In this way you will when device is shutdown and in your receiver set your AlarmManager again.