# Android Alarm manager not trigger the alarm when device time is changed manually

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have set up an alarm using the Alarm manager and to test it changed the time of the device manually. At this time the alarm not triggers, but if we wait till the time it gets triggered. Is there any better option to test the alarm?

The alarm setting code is given below.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                total,
                operation
            )
        } else {
            alarmManager.setExact(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                total,
                operation
            )
        }
```

Comment: You already tested it by waiting for timer to finish

Answer (score 0):

No that will not triggered by `AlarmManager`. So you should listen about time change actions and re-create the alarm.

Those actions are

```
Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK
Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED
```

[does Alarm Manager persist even after reboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034357/does-alarm-manager-persist-even-after-reboot) is a better answer to understand your problem and resolve that.

For more better understanding you may follow [Date and time change listener in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481386/date-and-time-change-listener-in-android)